# JWplayer video source is not working on mobile phones

Tags: jwplayer, live-streaming

I am trying to show a live stream on my website.It is working properly on desktop but not working on mobile phones. My script is as follows. The error is "resourse not found". Help me to fix this.

```
<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/JMFubNs4EeO+BCIACmOLpg.js"> </script>

<div id='playerQBUYpNLOBqmK'></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>

jwplayer('playerQBUYpNLOBqmK').setup({

    file:'http://livestream.5centscdn.com/athavantvvxtv/347697d21cd084a1796ce3ca18943611.sdp/playlist.m3u8',

    image: 'http://athavannews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/athavantv-card.jpg',

    title: '',

    autostart: false,

    width: '200',

    height: '150'

});
```

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: Are you using the same player / same key on desktop and mobile?